# Tracking Requirements for Map Android Development

Tags: android, permissions, location, android-manifest, mapquest

I'm trying to use the MapQuest API but when I go to start navigation, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User location tracking consent status was never set. 
User must be prompted for tracking consent to comply with legal requirements.
```

This seems like something that needs to be set in the Manifest as a permissions to comply with Europe's new privacy requirements, but I can't find what permission is required. I already have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION defined. Do you know what permission is needed?

Answer (score 0):

The [sample app](https://github.com/MapQuest/mq-navigation-sdk-reference-app-android) in the nav SDK documentation should cover what needs to be done to get the user's permission. The Traffic Data Collection: Requesting User Consent section of the [user guide](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/nav-sdk/android/v3.4/) discusses this in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

```
mNavigationManager.setUserLocationTrackingConsentStatus(UserLocationTrackingConsentStatus.GRANTED);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.